# Find input children of form, no matter how many parents they have

Tags: jquery, forms

How is it possible with jQuery, to find all inputs/textareas there is inside a form?
I know you can use .children and then .each, but i'm building a validation class and i dont know if some of the input has a wrapper because it should work for all my forms.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').children('input,textarea').each(function(){
        // do something with the input/textarea
    )};
});
```

This works, but only if the inputs is right after the form...

Comment: in "input" there are files, button, checkbox, radio .. do you want to include all ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get all descendants which matches a given selector:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input,textarea').each(function() {
        /* Do something with the input/textarea */
    });      
});
```

Comment: $(this).closest('form').find('input,textarea').not('input:submit'), is this ok to exclude the submit button ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I'd leave out `:`, because it's not needed. `$(this).closest('form').find('input,textarea').not('input[type=submit]')`will do the trick.

Comment: @SheikhHeera `input[type=submit]` is [preferred over `:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/).

Comment: Thank you! Didnt know .find worked for everything inside the element... tried .children().find('input, textarea') but no luck.. Works now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
    $('input,textarea', this.form).each(function(){
         // do something with the input/textarea
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "form.elements"

```
$(this).closest('form').elements.each(function(){
```

from vanilla js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Comment: shouldn't it be $(this).closest('form').get(0).elements.each(function(){ ?
since elements is a property of the dom element, not of the jquery object

Comment: that jquery object will be a dom element. from what i know you can use vanilla js properties with jquery exactly in the same way you can use jquery properties. but i haven't tested this particular piece of code from above ... in theory it should work. p.s. i think you must use '(0)' only on properties that return multiple dom elements and you want to select first element. but 'closest' will select only one dom element.